# Integrate $\int \frac{x^2}{(x \sin x + \cos x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Integrate $$\int^{\pi/4}_{0} \frac{x^2}{(x \sin x + \cos x)^2}dx$$

How can I integrate this ?

Question asks us to re-arrange the numerator

Comment: Hint: write $x^2$ as $x^2(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)$ and then add and subtract $x\cos x\sin x$. Try to look for the derivative of a quotient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we multiply by $\cos\left(x\right)
 $ the numerator and the denominator and we integrate by parts we have that $$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{x^{2}}{\left(x\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}dx= & \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{x}{\cos\left(x\right)}\frac{x\cos\left(x\right)}{\left(x\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}dx \\
 = & -\frac{2\pi}{4+\pi}+\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{\cos^{2}\left(x\right)}dx \\ = &-\frac{2\pi}{4+\pi}+1 \\
 = & \color{red}{\frac{4-\pi}{4+\pi}.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is a more natural way to calculate this integral than I suggested in the comment. It also shows that the suggested answer in the question is wrong.